# how to show the first letter of name and login name using redux login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using redux login and after login want to show the first letter of the user in span and user login details(name or email) in my header section so please give the solution??

```
here is my redux login code 

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    error: "",
    loading: false,
  },

  extraReducers: {
    [Login.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [Login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({ ...action.payload }))
      state.user = action.payload
    },
    [Login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload.message;
    },
    [SignUp.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [SignUp.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({ ...action.payload }));
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    [SignUp.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload.message;
    },
    [Logout.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [Logout.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      localStorage.removeItem("user", JSON.stringify({ ...action.payload }));
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    [Logout.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload.message;
    }
  }
});
```

here is my header code where enter details is the section where we have to enter the user login details to show the first letter of the user and name?

````
function Header() {
    const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

const logout = () =\> {
dispatch(Logout());;
navigate("/");
};

const htmlCode = () =\> {

    return (
       
      <span className="user-setting d-inline-block">
      <h3 className="username">{enter details}</h3>
      <span className="usericon">{enter details}</span>
      </span>
    )
}

```
I am trying to insert the {user.name} and other also but did not work??
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the store and the asyncthunk?
Is the reducer really named auth inside the store?
If everything is working you need to know what is going inside the user on the state, i will assume its an object like { name, email}, if that is the case then in the render you just have to do this { user.email } and to get the first letter use user.username.charAt(0)

============

Just to inform, useSelector re render the component based on the piece of state you select, if you will use just the user its better to use useSelector(state => state.auth.user ), that just matter if you have a complex component because react is fast